# Can i create separate properties file for Virgo OSGi bundle?

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, eclipse-virgo

I have Tomcat Virgo Server. I am deploying couple of OSGi bundles. I want to expose settings through properties, so the service within bundle can read it though Java `System.getProperty(String)` API. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use OSGis *ConfigurationAdmin* for doing this. You can deploy your properties files into *[VIRGO_HOME]/pickup* and then consume the properties from *ConfigurationAdmin* Service over the configurations *pid*. Virgo recognizes your properties files in its pickup folder and automatically exposes them over the *ConfigurationAdmin* Service. You could also list your properties files in a *plan* file if you use plans to deploy your bundles as an application.

Please refer to the official documentation on the Virgo Documentation Page [1] for further details.

And if you are using Spring/Blueprint you can stick to the property placeholder as you are used to. Just use the osgix namespace handlers and do something like this:

```
<osgix:cm-properties id="cmProps" persistent-id="com.xyz.myapp">
  <prop key="host">localhost</prop>
</osgix:cm-properties>
```

As by default the *persistent-id* or *pid* is the name of your properties file. For further reference have a look at Gemini Blueprint Documentation as well [2].

[1] http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-3.6.4.RELEASE/docs/virgo-programmer-guide/htmlsingle/virgo-programmer-guide.html#developing-applications-configuration-artifacts

[2] http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/documentation/reference/1.0.2.RELEASE/html/compendium.html#compendium:cm